# Referring document and window object as variable to shorten their reference

Tags: javascript

Okay. I know that this question might be marked as duplicate. I tried to search for an answer to existing question and did not find anything - so asking this question.

Can I do this for the sake of quicker coding? Is there any performance penalties? I am not sure if this will cache whole document DOM.

```
function(w, d, undefined) {
    d.querySelector('blah');
    w.location.href = 'yada.com';
}(window, document);
```

Comment: Yes. No. No. In fact, this used to be considered a good idea for speed (didn't have to go all the way back to the global scope to find the variables) but it's not really valid anymore.

Comment: ^^ can you explain a little more than that?

Comment: @JordanHendrix When accessing different variables in JS, the engine first checks the immediate scope for the reference to that variable. If it doesn't find it, it moves up to the parent scope. This repeats all the way to the global scope and returns `undefined` if nothing is found. That's how things like closures work. Since `window` and `document` are frequently accessed, engines generally optimize accessing them so you don't have to climb the whole chain every time. [Source](https://www.amazon.com/Performance-JavaScript-Faster-Application-Interfaces/dp/059680279X)

Comment: ^ As for the concern about caching the whole DOM, no. That won't happen. That implies that a copy would be made. You'd only be caching a reference to it. You can, more or less, think of it like you're saving a pointer to it.

Comment: thanks I think thats much clearer for him now. Prob worth posting as a real answer now

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @MikeC !